# The height and width for both column different (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently new to bootstrap and still wondering on the Grid system, currently facing a problem where the height for both column is different, is there anyway to make it same ?

Refer to Pic 1

[image: Pic when full width]

Also there is another problem when i reduce the size as im making it responsive, but when i reduce it to mobile size, the 2nd column did go down but the borders of the 2nd column does not match the first one.
Refer to Pic 2

[image: Mobile View]

Below is the Html code,

```
<h1 style="color:blue;">The History of Ice Cream</h1>
<div class="row bg-info" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="row col-md-6 bg-info" >
      <img class="px-3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601033402923-342909b0c151?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" width="100%" height="500px" alt="Nature of Mountain">
  </div>
  <div class="ml-5 col-md-6 bg-info">This is the beauty of nature</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: please include your css file also

Comment: you could have a parent container with a certain defined height, then set your row and cols to have a height of 100%. Your image could then be a background image with `object-fit: cover;`, or you could add the Bootstrap class `img-fluid` and/or `img-responsive` to make your image responsive as well.

Comment: Hi Martin, i removed the defined height at row, but if in mobile view, which as picture 2, when the 2nd column move down, the x axis doesnt fit as the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the two columns was not the same because you defined the height of the row.

If you make it to show divs in two-column in mobile view then you should use `col-sm` and also `col-xs`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 style="color:blue;">The History of Ice Cream</h1>
<div class="row bg-info">
  <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 bg-info" >
      <img class="px-3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601033402923-342909b0c151?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" width="100%" height="500px" alt="Nature of Mountain">
  </div>
  <div class="ml-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 bg-info">This is the beauty of nature</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mehedi Hasan Siam, after i removed the fixed height, it become the same when 2 column, but for the mobile view, i wanted to make it become 1 column which the 2nd column will auto move down, but currently it does move down but the x-axis borders of the 2nd column is not same with the first column, which show as the 2nd pic

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row bg-info py-3">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601033402923-342909b0c151?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" width="100%" height="500px" style="object-fit: cover;" alt="Nature of Mountain">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-2 pt-md-0">This is the beauty of nature</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row bg-info py-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601033402923-342909b0c151?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" width="100%" height="500px" style="object-fit: cover;" alt="Nature of Mountain">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-2 pt-md-0">This is the beauty of nature</div>
  </div>
</div>
```